# MIPS array assign infinity loop

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to fix this problem for hours!!!!! 
When I enter 8 integers for the array and then enter 0 to finish reading, when the loop section starts it goes to infinity loop!! 
I can't find where's the problem, when I remove the `addiu` from the `$s2` array it works fine but doesn't store the `$t1` on the array!

Please HELP!!

```
.data
array:  .space 32
percentage_Array: .space 32
newLine: .asciiz "\n"


.text
main:
        la $s1, array
        la $s2, percentage_Array

read_numbers:
        li $v0, 5
        syscall

        sw $v0, 0($s1)
        addiu $s1, $s1, 4

        beqz $v0, continue
        j read_numbers

continue:
        la $s1, array


loop:
        lw $t0, 0($s1)
        addiu $s1, $s1, 4

        beqz $t0, exit

        move $a1, $t0
        jal calculate_Ones_and_Bits

        move $s6, $v0
        move $s7, $v1

        #put the total number of ones
        add $s0, $s0, $s7 

        #calculate the percentage
        addi $t5, $zero, 100
        mult $s7, $t5
        mflo $t1
        div $t1, $s6
        mflo $t1

        #-----I THINK HERE IS MY PROBLEM------
        #Put the percentages on percentage_Array array
        sw $a1, 0($s2)
        addiu $s2, $s2, 4

        #Check which percentages are greater than 50 and print the numbers 
        which fulfill the condition
        slti $t2, $t1, 50
        beq $t2, 1, loop

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t0
        syscall

        #lines 66,67,68 are extra just for printing in new line more clearly
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, newLine
        syscall

        j loop

exit:
        #lines 73,74,75 are also extra just to print the value of s0, it is 
        printed here so it
        #will be executed after the loop has finished
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $s0
        syscall

        #tell the OS to exit/finish
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: Use a debugger to break into the program during the infinite loop. That will identify what is stuck. (Actually, this program is small enough that you could just step through the entire program one instruction at a time.)

Comment: The code you posted is not [MCVE], and there's no obvious problem, it's probably the missing part `calculate_Ones_and_Bits` which modifies `s2` register and doesn't restore it back to original value, so then you overwrite some other memory instead of storing result into percentage array. Try to comment `jal calculate_Ones_and_Bits` and put the fake result `li $v0,8` `li $v1,4` instead to verify the main loop works (I think it should). And use debugger to verify correctness of your code, checking only runtime results is very bad practice, as you can often receive correct output even with bugs.

Comment: Oh, there are more bugs I believe, like `sw $a1, 0($s2)` is actually not storing percentage value, that one is in `t1` register, not `a1`... but if you will single-step over the code in debugger, you may eventually catch all those small things, and also get some idea how to simplify the code a bit, to avoid some useless passing of values from one register to other where you can simply use just one register all the time, with a bit of planning. Allocating register usage in asm code is vital part of asm programming, it's a sparse resource. Also http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/